# Angular.js keypress events and factories

Tags: angularjs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm building an app in Angular and I'd like to have keypress events.
However, I'd prefer not to litter my code with a keypress here and a keypress there, but rather to put all keypress events into a single factory (or service) and then import this factory into my controllers to use.

I HOPE that doing things this way will make it easier for me to manage the keypress events and make sure I don't have conflicts (two events tied to the same keypresses) or something like that.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to manage this?

I'm using angular-ui-keypress.

As an example of how I'm hoping to use keypress events.

The user may have multiple tabs open and hits 'cmd+s' to save the files. 
Rather than a 'save' method being triggered on each of the open files, I've got an OpenFilesFactory, the keypress would map to the OpenFilesFactory.saveFiles method.

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a reason not to tie keyboard shortcuts to a factory rather than in a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing worked surprisingly well, and I'll opensource it as a module after a bit more work.

I  created a directive, which binds to the keypress events on $document

```
angular.module('keypress', []).directive('keypressEvents', 
  function($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function() {
        $document.bind('keypress', function(e) {
           $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress',e , String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        });
     }
   }
})
```

I then created a second directive for watching for keypresses on specific elements, basically giving the element a focus for key events.

```
angular.module('focus', []).directive('onFocus',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope) {
       scope.$on('keypress',function(e,parent_evt,key){
        if(scope.keyBindings[key]){
          scope.keyBindings[key](parent_evt, e); 
                          // params reversed so user goes up the chain
        }
       });
     }
   }
 });
```

In any controller where you want to use keyboard shortcuts, add a keybindings object

```
function keyedS(key, parent_evt, evt){
      // key is the key that was pressed
      // parent_evt is the keypress event
      // evt is the focused element object
}
$scope.keyBindings = {
    's': keyedS
}
```

Feedback?

I've actually put this together with multiple keybindings, so if the user selects 'ctrl-shift-s', that is what gets passed along the chain. Though I'm still struggling to find a really good way of getting all the press events. Eg. Tab doesn't work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you mean by having it be a separate resource.  To me, it seems to go against thinking in Angular, as events really should be "controlled."  If you want to have all keypress (or click) events centralized, maybe a switch/case is in order:

```
$scope.keypressHandler = function () {
switch ($event.keyCode)
{
case 13:
$scope.someEnterKeyFunction();
break;
default:
$scope.someDefaultFunction();
break;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how using switch comes into the solution. I'm trying to trigger an event in a factory, rather than through a controller, and the controllers listen to factory events already. Maybe I am just not understanding your complete solution.

Comment: I misread a little bit, but I think I'd still go for having the handling of the keypress events in the controller, and then farm out the actual logic to the factory function(s).  My reply was just in response to your initial line that you'd "prefer not to litter my code with a keypress here and a keypress there." A combination of switch/case in the controller for each potential keypress and then each of those calling their respective factory function, seems to at least structurally fit the bill.

Comment: gotcha, but I've got more than one controller that will be responding to keypress events. Hence the reason I'd like to keep all the keypress events together in one place, have the keypress affect the respective factories, and have the controllers listen for those factory events.