# angular.js listen for keypress as shortcut for button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, keypress

My first ever angular application is a pretty basic survey tool. I have multiple choice questions, with a button for each answer and a basic function that logs each answer on button click like this:

```
ng-click="logAnswer(answer.id)"
```

What I'm looking for is to be able to add a keypress event to the document that will listen for a keyboard response of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 which matches up with the button choices and calls the same function.

In searching around I can only find responses that relate to keypresses once a particular input field has focus, which doesn't help me. I did find the OPs response on this post [Angular.js keypress events and factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986240/angular-js-keypress-events-and-factories) which seems to be heading in the right direction, but I just can't work out how I get his directive to call my function.

I've included the directive in my js:

```
angular.module('keypress', []).directive('keypressEvents', 
  function($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function() {
        $document.bind('keypress', function(e) {
           $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress',e , String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        });
     }
   }
})
```

but I'm not sure how I make use of the keybinding object within my controller:

```
function keyedS(key, parent_evt, evt){
      // key is the key that was pressed
      // parent_evt is the keypress event
      // evt is the focused element object
}
$scope.keyBindings = {
    's': keyedS
}
```

How do I make the keybinding object listen for the keys I'm listening for and fire-off the function that I need?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Catch the event emitted by the rootscope in your controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('keypress', function (e, a, key) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.key = key;
    });
})
```

`key` is then yours to use in the controller.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/QaVLm/)

Comment: This one worked for me thanks @Jorg - having to add 'keypress-events' to a div eg.
`<div class="section-test" keypress-events>`
is an odd step which I was lucky to see in your fiddle and made it all work. I'm still finding angular a strange and mythical beast thanks to oddities like this, but hopefully I'll get there. Thanks!

Comment: It was helpful and I used your advice but I'm sadly not reputable enough to vote for a correct answer (which seems ridiculous to me - but hey - rules right?). I can offer you thanks!
EDIT: but I am an idiot and just realised I can accept your answer. derr.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using AngularJS to detect the keypress event, `ngKeypress` is what you want to use.

```
<!-- you can, for example, specify an expression to evaluate -->
<input ng-keypress="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">

<!-- or call a controller/directive method and pass $event as parameter.
     With access to $event you can now do stuff like 
     finding which key was pressed -->
<input ng-keypress="changed($event)">
```

You can check out the documentation for [`ngKeypress`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress) for more information. You might also want to check out the [`ngKeydown`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown) and [`ngKeyup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) directives.

Comment: thanks @rageandqq I did go through the angular docs but find them pretty unhelpful as they really lack any good examples. When you say 'insist on using angularJS to detect...' what do you mean? Isn't that the best way to deal with it? Or are you suggestion I should be using JS or JQuery to detect the keypresses instead?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would be to use jQuery to detect the keypress events.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already created a specific Keyboard shortcuts AngularJS module, have a look :

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys#angular-hotkeys-

Comment: I did try this but I couldn't work out how to get it to work. I'm new to angular and find the documentation in most places is pretty light-on and never really provides a complete example that I can learn from - too much assumed knowledge!

Comment: Do you know how to implement a module? Where did you stop? Did you succeed at injecting the dependance? Because once you get it, it's pretty simple. All I'm saying is that you have a "plugin" already made. The Github page is well documented, if you follow step-by-step you should not have issues.

Comment: :) I'm not sure what I can and can't do yet. I'm really struggling with not being able to console.log things in angular so I can't really tell how far I get a lot of the time! I followed the github instructions for the angular-hotkeys module but it kept throwing an error in angular.js. I have marked @Jorg's anwer below as correct because it gave me the outcome I needed with the code that I had. I realise that might not be the best but it's what I needed right now! I have some books on order but sadly the deadline comes first.

Comment: Books are not much compared to a live trial and error process. It forces you to pay attention to the console errors. "I followed the github instructions for the angular-hotkeys module but it kept throwing an error in angular.js". What was the error?

Answer (score 1):

### [function on specific keypress/keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698846/function-on-specific-keypress-keydown)

> Is is possible to call a function only when a specific key is pressed, like the spacebar? I've looked into [ngKeydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)
>
> ```
> <input ng-keydown="function()">
> ```
>
> But this will call the function on every keypress, is it possible to see what key was pressed, maybe within the function?

Use the `$event` object exposed by the `ng-keydown` directive.

```
 <input ng-keydown="fn($event)">
```

JS

```
 $scope.fn = function (event) {
     $scope.keyCode = event.keyCode;
     if (event.keyCode == 32) {
         console.log("spacebar pressed");
     };
 });
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/YS8UxPKWUy91BgXdkHHk?p=preview)

For more information on the `$event` object, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ngKeyup directive.  [Description of ngKeyUp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)

Use an array of functions for the various functions you need based on the keypress