# AngularJS - Directive causes the page to be blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, keypress

I have this directive that monitors the `keypress` event without focusing input field or something. Taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621833/angular-js-listen-for-keypress-as-shortcut-for-button). Modified it a little bit just to checkvar myApp = angular.module('userMain', []);

```
myApp.directive('keypressEvents', ["$document", "$rootScope", function ($document, $rootScope) {
    function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {

            var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            if(key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3) {
                alert(key);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, String.fromCharCode(e.which));
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

And here's the markup, rendered from a controller:

```
<div keypress-events>
    <div class="row question-content bg-warning">
        <p>{{ question.question }}</p>
    </div>

    <p>test template</p>
</div>
```

Whenever I run this page, I get a blank one. Without the markup even loaded!

The weird thing is when I press `1` for example, I get it in an alert box. Meaning that it's working. But it hinders any markup to be rendered.

Any help ?

Comment: Just adding this directive to one of my random plunks is working for me (i.e. alert is showing and the page is not blank)

Comment: @NewDev Hmmm, Can you think of a reason why is this happening to me ?

Comment: Not without seeing the rest of your code and errors. If you could reproduce this in plunker, I could take a look

Comment: Yes, your issue is not in your code that you have posted. I've tested it in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cr0o83cn/) and it is working.