# Angularjs selector with attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make something like that:

```
function keyupHandler(keyEvent){
   angular.element('div.keyFriendly[key='+keyEvent.key +']').click();
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get an error if I use `angular.element(document.querySelector('div.keyFriendly[key='+keyEvent.key +']'))`

[image]  I can make something like this:

```
function keyupHandler(keyEvent){
   let mass = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('div.keyFriendly'));
   for(let i=0;i<mass.length;i++){
       if(mass[i].attributes.key.value==keyEvent.key) mass[i].click();
   }
}
```

And this fulfills my needs. But I hope there is some way to make it more short and simple, NO?

Comment: Can you share the HTML? As you are using `Angular`, using `click()` seems to be anti-pattern

Comment: Please show your HTML.. `angular.element('div.keyFriendly[key='+keyEvent.key +']')` is going to match an element: `<div class="keyFriendlyKey" key="yourEventKey"></div>`

Comment: ok, give me 10 minutes

Comment: I don't get it. If your `click` triggers a function in Angular, why are you doing this? Why do you bother _selecting_ an element that's not even been generated by Angular yet, in order to simulate a click on it, in order to trigger a function? Why not trigger that function directly?

Comment: @Satpal  http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/1005/

Comment: @JeremyThille I just want to bind keyboard so user can work with application without mouse. Like in jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/1005

Comment: Why don't you just link the keyboard then? Like, `onPress=doSomething()` ? This element selection attempt is just not the way Angular works. Angular does not work by _selecting_ DOM elements and triggering clicks. That's the JS/jQuery approach.

Comment: @JeremyThille can you explain more detailed or show simple example? I will be very appreciate!

Comment: @JeremyThille you mean something like `$document.on('keyup', keyupHandler); function keyupHandler(keyEvent) { if (keyEvent.keyCode==??) doSomething()....`?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621833/angular-js-listen-for-keypress-as-shortcut-for-button

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm trying to make like you said: trigger a function to keypress, have made my variable in factory. On keypress value of variable changed, but DOM doesn't update. Why is it sow?

Comment: @JeremyThille http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/1006/ like that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not assigning the attributes value inside a string.

What you want is:

```
function keyupHandler(keyEvent){
   angular.element('div.keyFriendly[key="'+keyEvent.key +'"]').click();
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is that OP is trying to select an Angular-generated DOM element, in order to trigger a click, in order to execute a function. That's just not the way Angular works.